# Combining a future with a collection of futures (all to run at once) to supply a similarly structured lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, completable-future

I have a future and a list of futures,

```
CompletionStage<ParentEntity> p;
List<CompletionStage<ChildEntity>> cList;
```

I know for just a list, I can do

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(cList).thenSomething( ...
```

and use `.join()` to get each completed future.

So of course I could just combine `p` and `cList` into a single list, and simply consider index 0 the parent future. But, is there a way I can be more explicit with lambda parameters like:

```
CompletableFuture.foo(p, cList).thenBar((parentEntity, childEntityList) -> ...
```

Or, whatever. It's just that "remembering" the first index of a list meaning something special, doesn't seem right.

Comment: not really clear from the question what the intent is, do you want to simply ensure that `p` is processed before any of `cList` ?

Comment: No they should happen altogether. I'm just not happy with flattening all the futures into an indistinguishable list then picking the first out later. Was looking for a more semantics-preserving way.

Comment: Maybe just [CompletableFuture.thenCombine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenCombine) ?

Comment: @Zgurskyi - Unless I'm misunderstanding, thenCombine would wait for the results of either p or cList to carry onto either cList or p. I'd like them to run together.

Comment: @Andrew Cheong, `p` and `cList` will be executed concurrently. And when `p` and `cList` stage both complete normally, then supplied function is executed with the two results as arguments to the supplied function.

Comment: @Zgurskyi - Oh, I see now. So I have to do `p.thenCombine(allOf(cList), (pEntity, ...` Not sure how the rest of the syntax works out but I'll post it as an answer if I get there first. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was to `thenCombine` on two futures: a single future, and an `allOf` future (which various libraries provide).

I decided to use [Spotify's `allAsList`](https://github.com/spotify/completable-futures), like this:

```
p.thenCombine(allAsList(cList),
    (pEntity, cEntities) -> {
      // ...
    }
);
```

I'm sure other libraries provide the same. My codebase just happened to already be using this one already.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've got you right, try using this:

```
p.thenCombineAsync(allOf(cList), (pEntity, cEntities) -> {
   // do something
});
```